# How to get a specific attribute from an object in the database in Python Django?

Tags: python, django

For an assignement I have to create a website where a user can add other users from the database as his friends. To accomplish that I'd like to create a dropdownlist where the user can select other users under their firstname + lastname. However, how do I create a list with all user's names in it ? How do I make the drop down list ?

Here is my models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M','Male'),
        ('F','Female'),
        ('X','X'),
        )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

Here is my register_view in views.py :

```
def register_view(request):
    if 'email' in request.GET:
        newUser = User(firstname=request.GET['firstname'],
                      lastname=request.GET['lastname'], 
                      country=request.GET['country'],
                      email=request.GET['email'], 
                      phone=request.GET['phone'], 
                      password=request.GET['password'],
                      gender=request.GET['gender'])
        newUser.save()
        return redirect('/login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'register.html')
```

Please, help… I deeply apologize for my silly questions and my English since it is not my mother tongue. I however really need at least a breakthrough concerning this.

Many thanks !

Comment: How are you planning to develop your front-end? Are you using `django-forms`?

Comment: Should your list contain _all_ the "`firstname` + `lastname`"s from your `User` model? or you're going to exclude some of them (probably, at least one of them)?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean dropdown like [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/dropdowns/), pure Django maybe is not enough, try something like `bootstrap`, it is easy to use.
But if you don't feel like bothering to use some frontend framework, and just want a simple select input box with a submit button beside it, Django can do that.

First you will need to add a [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) field to track friends, and specify how to "show" those users:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    friends = models.ManyToManyField("self")

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M','Male'),
        ('F','Female'),
        ('X','X'),
        )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.firstname} {self.lastname}"
```

Then add a [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/) for the `User` model.

```py
from django import forms
from appname.models import User

class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

In view.py, pass it to the template

```py
def register_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # your code
        register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if register_form.is_valid():
            register_form.save()
        return redirect('/login')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        # your code
        register_form = RegisterForm()
        return render(
            request,
            'register.html',
            {
                'register_form': register_form,
            }
        )
```

Finally, render the form in the [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/):

```html
<form action="{% url 'appname:register' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

There might be many unfamiliar conceptions to you, leave a comment if anything confuses you.

Comment: Thank you for your really detailled answer. However, some questions remain :

When I try "From appname.models import User" in the models.py, they say there's an error due to unresolved import. How can that be ? There is not the same error when I write this line in the views.py.

Since I can't even advance to that point, I don't know what the result will be hence the Following question : I'd like to have the forms not in the register page when the User enters the database, but on the welcome page where the logged in User will be able to select friends. What should I change ?

Thanks !

Comment: @SoufianeAswin Wait, did you just literally copy `from appname.models import User` into your `models.py` file?

Comment: @SoufianeAswin You can try the User class from django `django.contrib.auth.models.User`, so that you can use django'API like `login()` `logout()`, then put the add friend form on your welcome page, that would be alot easier. But do remember to write your own code instead of copying from the answer, otherwise it won't work.